# POST Showing Undefined with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and I keep getting `undefined` as data when I submit the form. I looked online and tried `serialize()`, the `$.ajax` function, `$.post` function, amongst other methods to no avail.

I'm trying to accomplish a form submit without a page refresh. The code works fine if I comment out the script to remain on the page after form submission.

**index2.php**

```
<script>
function newlock() {
    $("#new-lock").load("new-lock.php");
}
</script>

<h3>Lock Settings</h3>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="newlock();">New Lock</a>
</div>

//code in between

<div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="new-lock"></div>
</div>
```

**insert_new_lock.php**

```
require "connect.php";

$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
$IP = $_POST['IP'];
echo $name;

$sql="INSERT INTO door_lock (lock_IP, lock_name)
VALUES
('$name','$IP')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

**new-lock.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<h2 align = "center"> Please enter information for the new lock </h2>
    <table border="0" align= "center">
        <form id="newlockform" action="insert_new_lock.php" method="post">
            <tr><td>Lock Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lock IP:</td> <td><input type="text" name="IP"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="reset" value="Clear"> <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit"></td></tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</html>

<script>
    $("#newlockform").submit(function() {

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var IP = $("#IP").val();

        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&IP=' +IP;

        $.post('insert_new_lock.php', dataString, function(data) {
            $("#tabs-1").html(data).fadeIn('100');
            $('#name,#IP').val(''); 
        }, 'text');
        return false;
});

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Before you work on the rest of this stuff, you **REALLY** need to read up about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Otherwise, enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: AGREED. I have much to learn. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have any `id` set on your form fields, so

```
    var name = $("#name").val();
```

is going to return null, which you then submit as an empty string. The form fields should loo like

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" id="name" />
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

for your JS code to work.